# Build file is not part of the build defined by settings file in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Today I do a new thing to my project, I add a new branch of gradle build file named `build-robot.gradle`(the old one named `build.gradle`). When I am using this command to build the project in build stage in jenkins(build using a different gradle config):

```
./gradlew :_robot-multibranch_feature_robot:soa-robot-api:build publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository -x test --build-file=build-robot.gradle
```

show this error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Build file '/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/_robot-multibranch_feature_robot/build-robot.gradle' is not part of the build defined by settings file '/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/settings.gradle'. If this is an unrelated build, it must have its own settings file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

the `settings.gradle` config like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'microservice'


include ":_robot-multibranch_feature_robot"
include ":_robot-multibranch_feature_robot:soa-robot-api"
include ":_robot-multibranch_feature_robot:soa-robot-service"
```

and this is the `build-robot.gradle` config:

```
project(":_robot-multibranch_feature_robot") {
    dependencies {
    }
}

project(":_robot-multibranch_feature_robot:soa-robot-api") {
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }
    archivesBaseName = "soa-robot-api"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
    dependencies {
        api("com.sportswin.soa:soa-misc-biz:1.0.0-RELEASE")
        api project(":packet:packet-api")
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'com.sportswin.soa'
                artifactId 'soa-robot-api'
                version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
                from components.java

                artifact sourceJar {
                    classifier "sources"
                }
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? "${dabaiSnapshotRepo}" : "${dabaiReleaseRepo}"
                url = "$url"
                credentials {
                    username "$mavenLoginName"
                    password "$mavenPassword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

project(":_robot-multibranch_feature_robot:soa-robot-service") {

    archivesBaseName = "soa-robot-service"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    bootJar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Start-Class': 'com.sportswin.soa.robot.AppStarter'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0")
        implementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.3")
        implementation("com.sportswin.soa:soa-robot-api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
        implementation project(":soa-user:soa-user-api")
        api project(":soa-red-envelope:soa-red-envelope-api")
        api project(":soa-happy-rain:soa-happy-rain-api")
        api project(":soa-happy-go:soa-happy-go-api")
        api project(":soa-happy-bomb:soa-happy-bomb-api")
        api project(":ws-red-envelope:ws-red-envelope-api")
        api project(":soa-wallet:soa-wallet-api")
        api project(":packet:packet-api")
        implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
    }

    test {
        useTestNG() {

        }
    }
}
```

I have read some similar question but still solve my problem. I want to using different build file in different branch. Am I missing something? what is the problem and what should I do to fix it?